# Set variable if empty or not defined with ansible

Tags: ansible

In my ansible vars file, I have a variable that will sometimes be set and other times I want to dynamically set it. For example, I have an RPM that I want to install. I can manually store the location in a variable, or if I don't have a particular one in mind, I want to pull the latest from Jenkins. My question is, how can I check if the variable is not defined or empty, and if so, just use the default from Jenkins (already stored in a var)?

Here is what I have in mind:

```
...code which gets host_vars[jenkins_rpm]
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Set Facts
    set_fact:
      jenkins_rpm: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['jenkins_rpm'] }}"

  - name: If my_rpm is empty or not defined, just use the jenkins_rpm
    set_fact: my_rpm=jenkins_rpm
    when: !my_rpm | my_rpm == ""
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `default` filter for that:

```
- set_fact:
    my_rpm: "{{ my_rpm | default(jenkins_rpm) }}"
```

Comment: This is exactly was I was looking for. Thanks! I just couldn't quite figure out how the default filter worked.